# how to change a field requirement in xml?

Tags: xml, view, odoo-8

I have a field "required"=True, and I want to change is to False in an inherited form.

```
      <field name="customer_id" position="replace">
               <attribute name="required">False</attribute>
      </field>
```

But I got :

```
      Integrity Error
The operation cannot be completed, probably due to the following:
- deletion: you may be trying to delete a record while other records still reference it
- creation/update: a mandatory field is not correctly set

[object with reference: customer_id - customer.id]
```

Comment: check the python file of customer_id if it's marked as  required=True then <attribute name="required">False</attribute> not work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In ODOO if a field is set as required=True in python file the you
>   **can't** marked it as required=Flase in xml file.

For making it's **non required** :

**Re-declare the field in the python file** with required=False.
because once a field is  declare `required=True` in python it **set to be required in database** also, but the same is not true in case of xml.

Hope it may help in your case.

Comment: Yes. In the end. That what i did. I re-declared the field the python. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
In xml file you can do  it: 
<field name="customer_id" position="attribute">
   <attribute name="required">False</attribute>
</field>

and in python code it is also possible to make required false.
If you want field required False in view add required=False in xml.
if you want field required False which is required True in parent (in database constrains) simply override it in inherited class.
```

Comment: it's position="attributes" not "attribute", thank you